# making firefox bookmarks global under Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, firefox, bookmarks

On Linux, ever since the days of Netscape Navigator and then with Mozilla Firefox
it has always been possible to store the bookmarks file in a global location on
the system so that every user that logs into such linux system gets this
set of system bookmarks to which each user can then add their own bookmarks.

How do I configure Firefox bookmarks to be shared across all users in Windows 7,
so that for instance, when I log in as administrator to perform some task I can
still quickly access the sites I need to access from within Firefox?

(Yeah, I could install the google bookmarks plugin, but that means having to
install it for every single user, and that's not what I want).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try and create a symlink between both bookmark files (places.sql I think it was).
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link

Comment: Can you provide a bit more detail about *how* the OP would do this? Answers with more detail are usually preferred to answers with just a link.

Comment: Thanks. I've found the following detailed page on how to use mklink on Windows Vista and Windows 7 to create Unix-like symbolic links: http://www.maximumpc.com/article/howtos/howto_master_your_file_system_mklink

Comment: I can't find the bookmarks file. I have no idea of where it is stored on Windows 7. Any ideas? I've looked in C:\Users\Neil\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\auxl183y.default (which is the only directory listed under the parent Profiles directory) but could not identify it.

Comment: http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/profiles-where-firefox-stores-user-data  there you can find all profile information. So bookmarks are in places.sqlite.

Comment: Thanks. I was able to type "about:support" (same as choosing Help -> Troubleshooting Information) from which my Profile Folder can be accessed. I can now see for instance C:\Users\John\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\auxl183y.default\bookmarkbackups\bookmarks-2013-10-12.json which indeed contains all of my bookmarks. This is handy, now I can just copy and paste the file wherever I like or use symlinks. On older mozilla versions the bookmarks file used to be an HTML file; now it is a JSON file. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know a possibility to share it like in linux. But I would recommend you, to install the Firefox addon [Sync](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/firefox-sync). It's from Mozilla itself and you can share easily your bookmarks with this addon. But you also can share many other informations, like passwords etc.(You can disable password-sharing etc. and only activate bookmarks of course)

You will have to create an account and add all accounts of your computer to sync, than you have your bookmarks available on all accounts.
Yes, it isn't really comfortable at first, but after this one-time-work you have good sync tool for firefox.

Also you can invite other devices and share your bookmarks with them.

**Install Sync**

1. [Download](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/firefox-sync)

**Setup Sync on the first account**

1. In the Firefox click the <kbd>Firefox</kbd>-button -> <kbd>Set Up Sync</kbd>.
2. Click <kbd>Create a New Account</kbd>.
3. Fill in your account-information
4. **IMPORTANT STEP**  You have to change the option, that only your bookmarks will get synced by clicking on the <kbd>Sync options</kbd>-button.
5. After you've edited your options, click  <kbd>Next</kbd>.

**Add second Account**

*Do these steps on the second account that you are trying to add to Firefox Sync.*

1. In the Firefox click the <kbd>Firefox</kbd>-button -> <kbd>Set Up Sync</kbd>.
2. In the next window choose "I Have an Account".
3. Because you want to add a second user account and not a pc choose "I don't have the device with me".
4. Sign in to your Sync account.
5. Click <kbd>Next</kbd>
6. Click Finish.

Now your bookmarks will be synced between these two accounts. You also can add more accounts of course by repeating the "Add second account"-steps.

Comment: Thanks for all this information but the link you provided points to a page saying the Sync software has been removed.